# Django: How to pass python variable value to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I've a function in views.py which returns latitude and longitude:

```
return render(request, 'map.html', {'lat_lng':lat_lng})
```

and I am able to access it in html file as `{{ lat_lng }}` but when I try to use `lat_lng` in separate **js** file then I'm not able to access it.

I tried all below stack answers but none worked for me:

[Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

[Passing django variables to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886765/passing-django-variables-to-javascript)

[How to use Django variable in JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689075/how-to-use-django-variable-in-javascript-file)

[Passing Python Data to JavaScript via Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445989/passing-python-data-to-javascript-via-django)

Comment: I answered a similiar question like this before. You might want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56844921/9958954

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) template tag. In your template do this

```
{{ lat_lng|json_script:"lat_lng" }}
```

Then in your javascript file you can access this variable like

```js
const lat_lng = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("lat_lng").textContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it is to append the following snippet at the top of your template html file(the one that imports your javascript file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const LAT_LNG = "{{ lat_lng }}"; // Or pass it through a function
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I am not expert in JS but I think I dont need to use script tag if I am using separate file but though I tried without script tag and it's printing lat_lng as it is and when I tried with script tag I am getting error as `Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: @ShinChan When reading the answer, it says: "_at the top of your template __html file___"

Answer (score 0):

Be sure when that getting the variable in a script tag is before including the separate js file
Exmple :

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var variable = "{{myV}}";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="myJsFile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to use lat_lng in separate js file then I'm not able to access it.

You can't use a django template variable in a static file. The static files will be returned in a way that bypasses Django's typical request processing.

Instead, set the variables on `data-*` attributes on an known HTML element, then get the element, access the attribute and use the value that way.